# Angular reuse function value from controller in view for an item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application which uses angular and in the view I call a controller function to hide/show a div but also needs the value from the return of the function. Code is as folowing

```
<div class="item-icon-right" ng_show="getClass(item.jsonpath) !== ''">
        <i class="icon ion-record getClass(item.jsonpath)"></i>
      </div>
```

You see that getClass is called twice for an item. Is it possible to store the value and reuse it?

Comment: Add `class` field in `item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store the returned value in new variable and use it for `i` class:

```
<div class="item-icon-right" ng_show="(itemClass = getClass(item.jsonpath)) !== ''">
    <i class="icon ion-record {{ itemClass }}"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<div class="item-icon-right" 
    ng-init="myVar=getClass(item.jsonpath)" ng_show="myVar !== ''">
        <i class="icon ion-record {{myVar}}"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: `ngInit` is not going to re-evaluated if `item.jsonpath` changes after.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **ngInit**,

```
<div ng-init="class = getClass(item.jsonpath)" class="item-icon-right" ng-show="class !== ''">
    <i class="icon ion-record {{class}}"></i>
</div>
```